# Hall System of a finite solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $\pi(G)$ be the prime divisors of $G$. For each $p\in \pi(G)$, let $S$ be the Sylow $p$-complement of $G$

If $\pi\subseteq \pi(G)$, let $\pi^* = \pi(G) \setminus \pi$.

Let $H_\pi = \bigcap \{ \;S \; |\; p \in \pi^*\}$. Then $\sum := \{ \; H_\pi \; |\; \pi\subseteq \pi(G) \} $ is a Hall system of $G$

I have already shown that $H_\pi$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. My problem lies in showing that if $\pi, \tau \subset \pi(G)$ then $H_\pi H_\tau = H_{\pi\, \cup \,\tau}$

I know that $H_\pi \cap H_\tau = \bigcap \{ \; S \; | \; p \in \pi^* \cup \tau^* \}$ and since $\pi^* \cup \tau^* = (\pi \cap \tau)^*$ by properties of complements, we have that $H_\pi \cap H_\tau = H_{\pi \,\cap \,\tau}$ by definition

Thus $|H_\pi H_\tau| = \dfrac{|H_\pi||H_\tau|}{|H_{\pi \,\cap \,\tau}|}$. What is the size of $|H_{\pi \,\cup \,\tau}|$?

Comment: What does "for set of primes $(\pi^*)'$" mean?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point that out. It means for the complement of $\pi^*$ i.e the primes that are in $\pi(G)$ but not in $\pi$.

Comment: I just worked out that $(\pi^*)^{\prime} \cap \pi(G) = \pi$, so that $H_\pi$ is indeed a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$

Comment: So then basically i want to show that the order of the Hall $(\pi \cup \tau)$-subgroup of $G$, $H_{\pi \cup \tau}$, is equal to $|H_\pi H_\tau|$

Comment: This follows immediately from the equation you have written on the last line.

Comment: I can see it follows intuitively or if I choose $\pi$ and $\tau$ from $\pi(G)$. Is there a nice way to show that it is true in general i.e to show that the prime divisors of $\dfrac{|H_\pi||H_\tau|}{|H_{\pi \,\cap \,\tau}|}$ are exactly those of $|H_{\pi \cup \tau}|$?